# Fresh grad hiring test quesiton

Tags: algorithm, output

It's a multiple choice question based question and the options donot contain -2147483642. the options are 10 ,11 etc

```
func min_jumps(arr[], start, end)
{
    if(start == end)
        return 0;

    int min = INT_MAX;  // Max value of int

    for(idx = 1; arr[start] >= idx AND end >= start + idx; idx++)
    {
        int jumps = min_jumps(arr, start + idx, end) + 1;
        if(min > jumps)
            min = jumps;
    }
    return min;
}

main()
{
    arr[] = [3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    ans = min_jumps(arr, 0, lenOfArr);
    print ans;
}
```

I tried to run the code and it only prints the

```
-2147483642
```

Comment: What language is this? It won't compile in either C nor C++. And what is "mcq"?

Comment: what is your question? If some multiple choice test is broken you best contact the authors of the test

Comment: Are you even supposed to run the code ? I don't get the point of a question if you could just run the code and get the answer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai yes it's a multiple choice test .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a bug.

When `min_jumps` doesn't find an answer, it returns `INT_MAX`.

When the caller adds `1` to the return value, it wraps around to `INT_MIN`, or   -2147483642.

You should point this out to whoever maintains the test (IF this is exactly the code on the test).

You should also point out that `AND` is not an operator in C or C++.